# Ошибка конвертации ui файла в py

Tags: python, конвертация, ui, gui, pyqt4

Создал `notepad.ui` файл в `Qt4 Designer` и попытался создать файл `notepadwindow.py` c помощью команды

```
pyuic4.bat notepad.ui -o notepadwindow.py
```

В результате получил следующую ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py" line 31, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
Import Error: DLL load failed: %1 далее что-то непонятное на другой кодировке Win32.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема была в 32-хбитности Python27 и 64-битности PyQt4,а ошибка состояла в том, что DLL не является приложением Win32. После установки 64-хбитной версии Python27 ошибка исчезла.